# Select specific custom post type from selected taxonomy on wordpress

Tags: custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

hello i have post_type "product" and taxonomy "price" can someone help me to query that custom post type with the selected taxonomy?

my current code is like this

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
$args = array(
 'post_type'   => 'product',
 'posts_per_page' => 5,
 'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'productcategories',
      'terms' => $term->name
    )
  )
);
query_posts($args);
print_r($args);?>
```

but nothing on result, can someone help me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

i'm found what wrong already.

nothing wrong with the code, i'm already solved it. that's because i'm not set the content into selected custom category yet, that why it display null.

my bad